# Am I using the Simpsons rule and Gauss-Legendre method correctly?

Tags: gaussian-integral, simpsons-rule

I have the integral here:

**Simpsons rule:** 
Answer 414.11411

**Gauss-Legendre method**

Here the limits are x+y
I found the answer to be around 0.923

Just wanted to make sure these values are correct.

Comment: The value of the integral is $3.481679$ , see here : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(x%3D10,14,1%2F((x-12)%5E2%2B1%2F2))

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that $\Gamma=2$ ? In this case, the first result is very good, but the second very inaccurate. What did you do exactly to get the second result ?

Comment: What is your $r$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Using $\Gamma=2$, the exact value is

$$\int_{-2}^2\frac{dm}{m^2+1}=2\arctan 2=2.2142974355881810060341309203571\cdots$$

A few values by the Gauss-Legendre method:

$$n=2\to1.714285714$$
$$n=3\to2.431372549$$
$$n=10\to2.214043446$$
$$n=20\to2.214297419$$

Don't forget the scaling factor.

Comment: @Tryingtopass: why do you do that, without a warning ? And why don't you answer the comments ?